# Error on windows: opus not found using pkg-config

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, telegram, opus

When I try to compile [TelegramDesktop](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop) code as shown as [instructions](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/dev/docs/building-msvc.md) I have an error while I am installing FFMPEG.
When I run
`bash --login ../patches/build_ffmpeg_win.sh`command

there is an error occured:
`ERROR: opus not found using pkg-config If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net. Include the log file "ffbuild/config.log" produced by configure as this will help solve the problem.`

There are some instructions how to install ffmpeg on ubuntu but can't find how to solve this on Windows 10?
Could anybody give me a hint?